# button hover makes downwards elements dance

Tags: html, css

I want to stop the bouncing of Forgot Password link on hover of login button. Every element that is beneath the button bounces when we hover in and out of the button. I have posted only a portion of the page for illustrating the problem.

I have tried reducing the border of the button on hover from 3px to 1px. But then  the hover effect isn't that obviously visible.

I can change the html structure if the need be. But not sure how to go about it.

```css
*:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 10px;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
}

div {
    display: block;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, menu, nav, section, summary {
    display: block;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: default;
}

* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after, .dl-horizontal dd:before, .dl-horizontal dd:after, .container:before, .container:after, .container-fluid:before, .container-fluid:after, .row:before, .row:after, .form-horizontal .form-group:before, .form-horizontal .form-group:after, .btn-toolbar:before, .btn-toolbar:after, .btn-group-vertical > .btn-group:before, .btn-group-vertical > .btn-group:after, .nav:before, .nav:after, .navbar:before, .navbar:after, .navbar-header:before, .navbar-header:after, .navbar-collapse:before, .navbar-collapse:after, .pager:before, .pager:after, .panel-body:before, .panel-body:after, .modal-header:before, .modal-header:after, .modal-footer:before, .modal-footer:after {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}

.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}

input, button, select, textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}

input {
    line-height: normal;
}

button, input, optgroup, select, textarea {
    margin: 0;
    font: inherit;
    color: inherit;
}

button, html input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"] {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #337ab7;
    border-color: #2e6da4;
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.active, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #178acc;
    border-color: lightslategrey;
    border-width: 3px;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #286090;
    border-color: #204d74;
}

.btn:hover, .btn:focus, .btn.focus {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<section id="loginSection">
  <form method="post" action="Index" role="form" id="loginForm" name="loginForm" >
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="UserName">User ID</label>
      <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control"
           id="UserName" name="UserName" type="text" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Password">Password</label>
      <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control"
           id="Password" name="Password" type="password" value="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" id="btnLogin" title="Login" name="btnLogin" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login" />
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <a href="/ForgotPassword">Forgot your password?</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Why not using `box-shadow` for hover, that won't change the size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the `.btn` have 3px transparent border

```
.btn {
    border: 3px solid transparent;
}
```

The idea is to make the width of the border stay the same, but only change the color on `:hover`

Answer (score 0):

Something else that would work is set a fixed height to the div that wraps your button.
You need to add a class to the wrapper first:

```
<div class="button-wrapper">
    <input type="button" id="btnLogin" title="Login" name="btnLogin" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login" />
</div>
```

And then add this to your CSS:

```
.button-wrapper {
    height: 35px;
}
```